# ajax loading a remote url to a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

Problem:

I am displaying news feeds from many sites. When I click on a link I want a modal panel to pop up and the modal panel must be loaded with the contents of the link.

Solutions Tried By Me:

1. Use the Jquery load,$.get methods to obtain content of the remote url.
   This works fine, except for the fact that sites in turn use relative urls in their html.
   For eg. ibm.com when referring to images have their source like

   `<img src="/some/relative/path/image.jpg" />`
2. Tried using iframe. It works fine on some sites, but some sites are prevented from being displayed in iframes and throw an error message

   Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.

   Please advise on an appropriate solution

Answer (score 0):

Its better you can use jquery `load` method

eg:- `$("#someDiv").load("external_url");`

Comment: Can you point me out to the section which educates me that the relative urls issue will not occur or can you post a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a jQuery.load approach, then you would need a bit of workaround in order to fix the relative URLs issue.

The load method has a callback option, you can use that to fix the injected relative URLs.

You can do something like this:

```
var baseSite = "http://www.somewhere.com";
var baseURL = "/your/folder/";
var container = $('#container').load(baseSite+baseURL+"your-page.html", function(){
    //once you're here, DOM has been updated already!

    //fix relative URLs like "../assets/img/logo.png"
    container.find("img[src^='/']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', baseSite+baseURL+$(this).attr('src'));
    });

    //fix absolute URLs like "/base/path/img/logo.png" (needed only if different domain!)
    container.find("img[src$='/']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', baseSite+$(this).attr('src'));
    });

    //TODO: the same for links!
});
```